# Setting tasks at a future date on a SQS-based worker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, amazon-sqs

We're looking for some advices/strategies on how to schedule tasks at a future time using AWS Simple Queue Service (SQS) and a worker written in Node.js.

Tasks have to be scheduled at, for example, "2 hours from now". Unlike cron jobs, they're not periodical, and they have to be executed exactly 2 hours after being scheduled (it doesn't need to be accurate down to the second, however).
Of course, they also need to be stored in a sort of persistent database until they're executed. So, having them in memory on the server (for example just waiting for a `setTimeout` to be fired) wouldn't work.

Any idea on how we could manage that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using sqs here is really the best use case. However if you must then there are 2 options. 
1. There is an option to delay message delivery when you post the message to queue. That means the message is not delivered to any one for that time. But this value can not be more than 15 minutes. 
2. You can read the message in the consumer application and then if the action is yet not to be performed then just change the visibility timeout of that one message so that the message is not made available to any other consumer till the time the said action is not to be performed.

Comment: Interesting, it could work but I don't think it would be really ideal. You're talking about SQS not being the best one here, and I may agree... But what else could we use with Elastic Beanstalk workers? (if it matters, we use Node.js)

Comment: I might suggest you to use simple workflow for this. Using swf you can schedule an activity for whatever time you want to. Instead of putting the message Into the queue you could just start a new wf which would schedule the job after a said interval. All you have to do is set the timer in code and the activity will execute by itself at that time. You could also use the same workflow to perform step 2 after step 1 has finished like may be sending notification to someone that the job is done.

Comment: I understand, but how can I integrate SWF with Elastic Beanstalk workers?

Comment: If using Java and swf, the deplorable unit can be a jar file or a war file and you can integrate the same with bean stalk the same way as any other deployable.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I'm still following you here. My knowledge of SWF is limited, but I thought Elastic Beanstalk Workers used only SQS? Secondly, we are using JavaScript, not Java!